# Display multiple images in one IPython Notebook cell?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

If I have multiple images (loaded as NumPy arrays) how can I display the in one IPython Notebook cell?

I know that I can use `plt.imshow(ima)` to display *one* image… but I want to show more than one at a time.

I have tried:

```
 for ima in images:
     display(Image(ima))
```

But I just get a broken image link:

[image]

Comment: If using `imshow` is an option, why not using it in combination with `subplots` to create an array of images? Do the image sizes vary a lot?

Comment: I could use subplots… but that gets fiddly when I'm just experimenting: I need to set the number of rows and columns, then if there are too many rows and columns I need to increase the figure size to make sure they are each individually reasonably sized, and I need to wait for the entire figure to render before I can see the individual images (as opposed to their being displayed as they are generated)

Comment: Do you use python 3.3? And is something written to the console?

Comment: No - this is Py2.7. And what do you mean, "is something written to the console"? Do you mean when I go to `display(Image(…))`? In that case, it looks like the image has something like `src="data:np.array([…])"`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Short answer:

call `plt.figure()` to create new figures if you want more than one in a cell:

```py
for ima in images:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(ima)
```

But to clarify the confusion with `Image`:

`IPython.display.Image` is for displaying Image *files*, not array data. If you want to display numpy arrays with Image, you have to convert them to a file-format first (easiest with PIL):

```py
from io import BytesIO
import PIL
from IPython.display import display, Image

def display_img_array(ima):
    im = PIL.Image.fromarray(ima)
    bio = BytesIO()
    im.save(bio, format='png')
    display(Image(bio.getvalue(), format='png'))

for ima in images:
    display_img_array(ima)
```

A [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/7076095) illustrating both approaches.

Comment: Subtle point from the linked notebook: You need to do `%matplotlib inline` if you want the images to appear.

Comment: Is there any good explanation of why I have to `plt.figure()` before each each image?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid sending the images to disk? I do have a bunch of in-memory images that are manipulated many times - *in memory*.

Answer (score 106):

This is easier and works:

```
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.display import display
x = Image(filename='1.png') 
y = Image(filename='2.png') 
display(x, y)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed - I wasn't using numpy arrays or actual plots, I just had .pngs to display, and this was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: This should very much be the accepted answer. If you have an array of images, this works: `display(*images)`

Comment: I like this, but it displays images much larger than `plt.imshow()`. [It does't seem possible to control the size](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display).

Answer (score 99):

## Horizontal layout

[image: Horizontal layout demonstration]

### Short answer

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
columns = 5
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    plt.subplot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
```

### Long answer

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

images = []
for img_path in glob.glob('images/*.jpg'):
    images.append(mpimg.imread(img_path))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
columns = 5
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    plt.subplot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: This is a great and more useful answer!

Comment: This is a great way to enumerate multiple figures

Comment: Number of rows should be an integer.

Change plt.subplot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1) to plt.subplot(int(len(images) / columns + 1), columns, i + 1)

Answer (score 25):

You can do it really fast and easy with [IPyPlot](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot):

```
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(images_array, max_images=20, img_width=150)
```

You would get a plot similar to this:
[image]

It's using `IPython.display` and `HTML` under the hood and it can take images in following formats:

- `string` file paths
- `PIL.Image` objects
- `numpy.ndarray` objects representing images

It would take just a few seconds to display a `numpy array` of 500 images

Answer (score 18):

You can display multiple images in one IPython Notebook cell by using display and HTML functions. You need to create the set of html img tags as a string as follows

```
from IPython.display import Image, HTML, display
from glob import glob
imagesList=''.join( ["<img style='width: 120px; margin: 0px; float: left; border: 1px solid black;' src='%s' />" % str(s) 
                 for s in sorted(glob('yourimage*.png')) ])
display(HTML(imagesList))
```

See a example of use from  http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/PBrockmann/Dodecahedron

You may need to refresh your browser (shift + load) to see new images if they have been 
changed from a previous cell.

Comment: Is it possible to save this rendering to file, somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Today, I faced this problem in google Colab and jupyter notebook and I would share a simple solution on MNIST dataset:

```
for index in range(1,6):
    plt.imshow(train_set.dataset[index], cmap='gray')
```

The output only shows the last image:

[image]

Because the cell in both IDEs shows only the last image. Thus I added `plt.show()` to fix this issue:

```
for index in range(1,6):
    plt.imshow(train_set.dataset[index], cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

**Last comment:** I like this way because I can add `input() and plot() functions` together in the loop not like other methods I tried.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind an additional dependency here is a two liner using [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/):

```
from skimage.util import montage
plt.imshow(montage(np.array(images), multichannel=True))
```

Set `multichannel=True` for color images and `multichannel=False` for grayscale images.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a few years now since this question has been asked, but it's sad that this feature has not managed to get into the core of jupyter notebooks.

I would expect an `imshow` function that's simple enough that

- accepts a single or multiple images as input
- layouts them neatly for me even if there are 100 images

and looks something like:

```
imshow(img)
imshow(img1, img2)
imshow(*imgs[:100])
```

Some nice to have optional arguments:

- title
- size
- rows and/or columns
- cmap

Unfortunately, that function doesn't as part of the notebooks. Hopefully, that will be there in the future. For now, I have that exact function `imshow` implemented in the [imshowtools](https://pypi.org/project/imshowtools/) package. It uses matplotlib under the hood.

Say you have MNIST and `imshow` loaded using

```py
from imshowtools import imshow
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Then you can simply use

```py
imshow(x_train[0])
imshow(x_train[0], x_train[1], x_train[2])
imshow(*x_train[:20], cmap='binary')
imshow(*x_train[:100], cmap='binary', size=(10, 10))
```

[image: mnist_img]

Sometimes, you want them in one row or in one column:

```py
imshow(*x_train[:15], cmap='Purples', rows=1)
imshow(*x_train[:24], cmap='Greens', columns=4)
```

[image: mnist_rows_cols]

Answer (score 2):

Somehow related to this question (and since I was directed to this answer when I was trying to solve it), I was able to solve a similar problem by simply typing the full file-path when calling `Image()`. In my case, I had to choose a random image from different folder paths stored in a list `your_folder` and display them.

```
import random, os 
for i in range(len(your_folder)):
   ra1 = "../"+your_folder[i]+"/"+random.choice(os.listdir(your_folder[i]))
   image = Image(ra1)
   display(image)
```

Comment: you should use `os.path.join` or `pathlib.Path` to assemble paths in an os-agnostic way.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, imshow, axis
from matplotlib.image import imread

mypath='.'
hSize = 5
wSize = 5
col = 4

def showImagesMatrix(list_of_files, col=10):
    fig = figure( figsize=(wSize, hSize))
    number_of_files = len(list_of_files)
    row = number_of_files/col
    if (number_of_files%col != 0):
        row += 1
    for i in range(number_of_files):
        a=fig.add_subplot(row,col,i+1)
        image = imread(mypath+'/'+list_of_files[i])
        imshow(image,cmap='Greys_r')
        axis('off')

showImagesMatrix(listOfImages,col)
```

based on @Michael answer

Answer (score 1):

The answers in this thread helped me: [Combine several images horizontally with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python)

The problem of using matplotlib was the displayed images' definition was really bad. I adapted one of the answers there to my needs:

The following code displays the images concatenated horizontaly in a jupyter notebook. Notice the commented line with the code to save the image if you'd like that.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
from IPython.display import display

list_im = ['Test1.jpg', 'Test2.jpg', 'Test3.jpg']
imgs    = [ PIL.Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]
# pick the image which is the smallest, and resize the others to match it (can be arbitrary image shape here)
min_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )

# save that beautiful picture
imgs_comb = PIL.Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
#imgs_comb.save( 'combo.jpg' )    

display(imgs_comb)
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @ChaosPredictor answer

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, imshow, axis
from matplotlib.image import imread

def showImagesMatrix(list_of_files, col=10, wSize=5, hSize=5, mypath='.'):
    fig = figure(figsize=(wSize, hSize))
    number_of_files = len(list_of_files)
    row = number_of_files / col
    if (number_of_files % col != 0):
        row += 1
    for i in range(number_of_files):
        a=fig.add_subplot(row, col, i + 1)
        image = imread(mypath + '/' + list_of_files[i])
        imshow(image, cmap='Greys_r')
        axis('off')
```

then

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('.')
num_images = 30
list_of_image_paths = [str(x) for x in list(p.glob('../input/train/images/*'))[:num_images]]

showImagesMatrix(list_of_image_paths)

# or with named args
showImagesMatrix(list_of_image_paths, wSize=20, hSize=10, col=5)
```

[image: matplotlib image grid]

Answer (score 0):

I used @dval suggestion to display network graphs build with graphviz, and it works directly (no need to create image)

```
from IPython.display import display
dot1 = Digraph()

# Add nodes
dot1.node('1')
dot1.node('3')
dot1.node('2')
dot1.node('5')

# Add edges
dot2= dot1.copy()
dot2.edges(['12', '13', '35'])
 
display(dot1,dot2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K4SI.png)