# Combine several images horizontally with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-2.x, paste

I am trying to horizontally combine some JPEG images in Python.

### Problem

I have 3 images - each is 148 x 95 - see attached. I just made 3 copies of the same image - that is why they are the same.

[image][image][image]

### My attempt

I am trying to horizontally join them using the following code:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

list_im = ['Test1.jpg','Test2.jpg','Test3.jpg']

# creates a new empty image, RGB mode, and size 444 by 95
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (444,95))

for elem in list_im:
    for i in xrange(0,444,95):
        im=Image.open(elem)
        new_im.paste(im, (i,0))
new_im.save('test.jpg')
```

However, this is producing the output attached as `test.jpg`.

[image]

### Question

Is there a way to horizontally concatenate these images such that the sub-images in test.jpg do not have an extra partial image showing?

#### Additional Information

I am looking for a way to horizontally concatenate n images. I would like to use this code generally so I would prefer to:

- not to hard-code image dimensions, if possible
- specify dimensions in one line so that they can be easily changed

Comment: Why is there a `for i in xrange(...)` in your code? Shouldn't `paste` take care of the three image files you specify?

Comment: question, will your images always be the same size ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Image Library: How to combine 4 images into a 2 x 2 grid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567409/python-image-library-how-to-combine-4-images-into-a-2-x-2-grid)

Comment: dermen: yes, images will always be the same size. msw: I wasn't sure how to loop through the images, without leaving a blank space in between - my approach is probably not the best to use.

Comment: The only reason why this doesn't work is because of your `xrange(0,444,95)`. If you change this to `xrange(0,444,148)` everything should be fine.

This is because you split the images horizontally, and the width of one image is 148.
(Also, you want to combine 3 images, so it is logical that your range object should contain 3 values.)

Comment: Thanks! You are right about the width part. I did make use of this in the question, but my reasoning about the step size was wrong - see `Image.new('RGB', (444,95))`...here, I specified 444 since, as you also quite correctly pointed out, there were three images and each has a width of 148 pixels so the concatenated image width should be 148 X 3 = 444. Nonetheless, you are correct - `xrange` was incorrectly used. I thought 95 would be the height of the final image, which was a wrong assumption since that is not how [`xrange` worked](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange).

Answer (score 279, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

images = [Image.open(x) for x in ['Test1.jpg', 'Test2.jpg', 'Test3.jpg']]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
  new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
  x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('test.jpg')
```

`Test1.jpg`

[image: Test1.jpg]

`Test2.jpg`

[image: Test2.jpg]

`Test3.jpg`

[image: Test3.jpg]

`test.jpg`

[image]

---

The nested for `for i in xrange(0,444,95):` is pasting each image 5 times, staggered 95 pixels apart. Each outer loop iteration pasting over the previous.

```
for elem in list_im:
  for i in xrange(0,444,95):
    im=Image.open(elem)
    new_im.paste(im, (i,0))
  new_im.save('new_' + elem + '.jpg')
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Two questions: 1. `x_offset = 0` - is this is the stagger between image centers? 2. For a vertical concatenation, how does your approach change?

Comment: The second argument of paste is a box. "The box argument is either a 2-tuple giving the upper left corner, a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate, or None (same as (0, 0))." So in the 2-tuple we are using `x_offset` as `left`. For vertical concat, keep track of the `y-offset`, or `top`.  Instead of `sum(widths)` and `max(height)`, do `sum(heights)` and `max(widths)` and use the second argument of the 2-tuple box. increment `y_offset` by `im.size[1]`.

Comment: Nice solution. Note in python3 that maps can only be iterated over once, so you'd have to do images = map(Image.open, image_files) again before iterating through the images the second time.

Comment: Jaijaba I also ran into the problem you describe, so I edited DTing's solution to use a list comprehension instead of a map.

Comment: I had to use list comprehension instead of `map` in python3.6

Comment: Noting the same thing as Naijaba: in python3 `map` returns an iterator, however instead of calling `map` twice, you could could create a list from the iterator `list(map(Image.open, infile_paths))` or use a list comprehension `[Image.open(path) for path in infile_paths]`.

Comment: May I ask why are you importing `sys`?

Answer (score 127):

I would try this:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image

list_im = ['Test1.jpg', 'Test2.jpg', 'Test3.jpg']
imgs    = [ Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]
# pick the image which is the smallest, and resize the others to match it (can be arbitrary image shape here)
min_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
imgs_comb = np.hstack([i.resize(min_shape) for i in imgs])

# save that beautiful picture
imgs_comb = Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
imgs_comb.save( 'Trifecta.jpg' )    

# for a vertical stacking it is simple: use vstack
imgs_comb = np.vstack([i.resize(min_shape) for i in imgs])
imgs_comb = Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
imgs_comb.save( 'Trifecta_vertical.jpg' )
```

It should work as long as all images are of the same variety  (all RGB, all RGBA, or all grayscale). It shouldn't be difficult to ensure this is the case with a few more lines of code. Here are my example images, and the result:

## Test1.jpg

[image: Test1.jpg]

## Test2.jpg

[image: Test2.jpg]

## Test3.jpg

[image: Test3.jpg]

## Trifecta.jpg:

[image: combined images]

## Trifecta_vertical.jpg

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another good answer. How would `min_shape =....` and `imgs_comb....` change for a vertical concatenation? Could you post that here as a comment, or in your reply?

Comment: For vertical , change ```hstack``` to ```vstack```.

Comment: One more question: Your first image (**Test1.jpg**) is larger than the other images. In your final (horizontal or vertical) concatenated image, all the images are the same size. Could you explain how you were able to shrink the first image before concatenating it?

Comment: I used ```Image.resize``` from PIL.  ```min_shape``` is a tuple of (min_width, min_height) and then ```(np.asarray( i.resize(min_shape) ) for i in imgs )``` will shrink all images to that size. In fact, ```min_shape``` can be any ```(width,height)``` you desire, just keep in mind that enlarging low-res images will make them blurry!

Comment: If you are looking to just combine images together without any specifics, this is probably the most simple and most flexible answer here. It accounts for differing image size, any # of images, and varying picture formats. This was a very well thought out answer and EXTREMELY useful. Would have never thought of using numpy. Thank you.

Answer (score 29):

Edit: DTing's answer is more applicable to your question since it uses PIL, but I'll leave this up in case you want to know how to do it in numpy.

Here is a numpy/matplotlib solution that should work for N images (only color images) of any size/shape.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def concat_images(imga, imgb):
    """
    Combines two color image ndarrays side-by-side.
    """
    ha,wa = imga.shape[:2]
    hb,wb = imgb.shape[:2]
    max_height = np.max([ha, hb])
    total_width = wa+wb
    new_img = np.zeros(shape=(max_height, total_width, 3))
    new_img[:ha,:wa]=imga
    new_img[:hb,wa:wa+wb]=imgb
    return new_img

def concat_n_images(image_path_list):
    """
    Combines N color images from a list of image paths.
    """
    output = None
    for i, img_path in enumerate(image_path_list):
        img = plt.imread(img_path)[:,:,:3]
        if i==0:
            output = img
        else:
            output = concat_images(output, img)
    return output
```

Here is example use:

```
>>> images = ["ronda.jpeg", "rhod.jpeg", "ronda.jpeg", "rhod.jpeg"]
>>> output = concat_n_images(images)
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.imshow(output)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your `output = concat_images(output, ...` is what I was looking for when I started searching for a way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ballsatballsdotballs, I have one question regarding your answer. If I want to add the sub-title for each sub-images, how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a function generalizing previous approaches, creating a grid of images in PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def pil_grid(images, max_horiz=np.iinfo(int).max):
    n_images = len(images)
    n_horiz = min(n_images, max_horiz)
    h_sizes, v_sizes = [0] * n_horiz, [0] * (n_images // n_horiz)
    for i, im in enumerate(images):
        h, v = i % n_horiz, i // n_horiz
        h_sizes[h] = max(h_sizes[h], im.size[0])
        v_sizes[v] = max(v_sizes[v], im.size[1])
    h_sizes, v_sizes = np.cumsum([0] + h_sizes), np.cumsum([0] + v_sizes)
    im_grid = Image.new('RGB', (h_sizes[-1], v_sizes[-1]), color='white')
    for i, im in enumerate(images):
        im_grid.paste(im, (h_sizes[i % n_horiz], v_sizes[i // n_horiz]))
    return im_grid
```

It will shrink each row and columns of the grid to the minimum. You can have only a row by using pil_grid(images), or only a column by using pil_grid(images, 1).

One benefit of using PIL over numpy-array based solutions is that you can deal with images structured differently (like grayscale or palette-based images).

*Example outputs*

```
def dummy(w, h):
    "Produces a dummy PIL image of given dimensions"
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    im = Image.new('RGB', (w, h), color=tuple((np.random.rand(3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    points = [(i, j) for i in (0, im.size[0]) for j in (0, im.size[1])]
    for i in range(len(points) - 1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            draw.line(points[i] + points[j], fill='black', width=2)
    return im

dummy_images = [dummy(20 + np.random.randint(30), 20 + np.random.randint(30)) for _ in range(10)]
```

`pil_grid(dummy_images)`:

[image: line.png]

`pil_grid(dummy_images, 3)`:

[image]

`pil_grid(dummy_images, 1)`:

[image]

Comment: This line in pil_grid:
`h_sizes, v_sizes = [0] * n_horiz, [0] * (n_images // n_horiz) `
should read:
`h_sizes, v_sizes = [0] * n_horiz, [0] * ((n_images // n_horiz) + (1 if n_images % n_horiz > 0 else 0))`

Reason: If the horizontal width does not divide the number of images in integers, you need to accomodate for the additional if incomplete line.

Answer (score 13):

Based on DTing's answer I created a function that is easier to use:

```
from PIL import Image


def append_images(images, direction='horizontal',
                  bg_color=(255,255,255), aligment='center'):
    """
    Appends images in horizontal/vertical direction.

    Args:
        images: List of PIL images
        direction: direction of concatenation, 'horizontal' or 'vertical'
        bg_color: Background color (default: white)
        aligment: alignment mode if images need padding;
           'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom', or 'center'

    Returns:
        Concatenated image as a new PIL image object.
    """
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    if direction=='horizontal':
        new_width = sum(widths)
        new_height = max(heights)
    else:
        new_width = max(widths)
        new_height = sum(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (new_width, new_height), color=bg_color)


    offset = 0
    for im in images:
        if direction=='horizontal':
            y = 0
            if aligment == 'center':
                y = int((new_height - im.size[1])/2)
            elif aligment == 'bottom':
                y = new_height - im.size[1]
            new_im.paste(im, (offset, y))
            offset += im.size[0]
        else:
            x = 0
            if aligment == 'center':
                x = int((new_width - im.size[0])/2)
            elif aligment == 'right':
                x = new_width - im.size[0]
            new_im.paste(im, (x, offset))
            offset += im.size[1]

    return new_im
```

It allows choosing a background color and image alignment. It's also easy to do recursion:

```
images = map(Image.open, ['hummingbird.jpg', 'tiger.jpg', 'monarch.png'])

combo_1 = append_images(images, direction='horizontal')
combo_2 = append_images(images, direction='horizontal', aligment='top',
                        bg_color=(220, 140, 60))
combo_3 = append_images([combo_1, combo_2], direction='vertical')
combo_3.save('combo_3.png')
```

[image: Example concatenated image]

Comment: I'm not 100% on where the issue is, but this function does something weird with images, causing the objects i'm iterating over to go from total weight of 25mb to 2gb.  so be careful using this method

Answer (score 8):

If all image's heights are same,

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

imgs = ['a.jpg', 'b.jp', 'c.jpg']
concatenated = Image.fromarray(
  np.concatenate(
    [np.array(Image.open(x)) for x in imgs],
    axis=1
  )
)
```

Maybe you can resize images before the concatenation like this,

```
import numpy as np

imgs = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg']
concatenated = Image.fromarray(
  np.concatenate(
    [np.array(Image.open(x).resize((640,480)) for x in imgs],
    axis=1
  )
)
```

Comment: Simple and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
from PIL import Image


def join_images(*rows, bg_color=(0, 0, 0, 0), alignment=(0.5, 0.5)):
    rows = [
        [image.convert('RGBA') for image in row]
        for row
        in rows
    ]

    heights = [
        max(image.height for image in row)
        for row
        in rows
    ]

    widths = [
        max(image.width for image in column)
        for column
        in zip(*rows)
    ]

    tmp = Image.new(
        'RGBA',
        size=(sum(widths), sum(heights)),
        color=bg_color
    )

    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        for j, image in enumerate(row):
            y = sum(heights[:i]) + int((heights[i] - image.height) * alignment[1])
            x = sum(widths[:j]) + int((widths[j] - image.width) * alignment[0])
            tmp.paste(image, (x, y))

    return tmp


def join_images_horizontally(*row, bg_color=(0, 0, 0), alignment=(0.5, 0.5)):
    return join_images(
        row,
        bg_color=bg_color,
        alignment=alignment
    )


def join_images_vertically(*column, bg_color=(0, 0, 0), alignment=(0.5, 0.5)):
    return join_images(
        *[[image] for image in column],
        bg_color=bg_color,
        alignment=alignment
    )
```

For these images:

```
images = [
    [Image.open('banana.png'), Image.open('apple.png')],
    [Image.open('lime.png'), Image.open('lemon.png')],
]
```

Results will look like:

---

```
join_images(
    *images,
    bg_color='green',
    alignment=(0.5, 0.5)
).show()
```

[image]

---

```
join_images(
    *images,
    bg_color='green',
    alignment=(0, 0)

).show()
```

[image]

---

```
join_images(
    *images,
    bg_color='green',
    alignment=(1, 1)
).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is also [skimage.util.montage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.montage) to create a montage of images of the same shape:

```py
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from skimage.util import montage

list_im = ['Test1.jpg', 'Test2.jpg', 'Test3.jpg']
imgs    = [ np.array(Image.open(i)) for i in list_im ]

montage(imgs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
""" 
merge_image takes three parameters first two parameters specify 
the two images to be merged and third parameter i.e. vertically
is a boolean type which if True merges images vertically
and finally saves and returns the file_name
"""
def merge_image(img1, img2, vertically):
    images = list(map(Image.open, [img1, img2]))
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    if vertically:
        max_width = max(widths)
        total_height = sum(heights)
        new_im = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))

        y_offset = 0
        for im in images:
            new_im.paste(im, (0, y_offset))
            y_offset += im.size[1]
    else:
        total_width = sum(widths)
        max_height = max(heights)
        new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

        x_offset = 0
        for im in images:
            new_im.paste(im, (x_offset, 0))
            x_offset += im.size[0]

    new_im.save('test.jpg')
    return 'test.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
from pil import Image

files = [
      '1.png',
      '2.png',
      '3.png',
      '4.png']

result = Image.new("RGB", (800, 800))

for index, file in enumerate(files):
path = os.path.expanduser(file)
img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
x = index // 2 * 400
y = index % 2 * 400
w, h = img.size
result.paste(img, (x, y, x + w, y + h))

result.save(os.path.expanduser('output.jpg'))
```

---

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the solutions already suggested. Assumes same height, no resizing.

```
import sys
import glob
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 100000000  # For PIL Image error when handling very large images

imgs    = [ Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]

widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in imgs))
total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

# Place first image
new_im.paste(imgs[0],(0,0))

# Iteratively append images in list horizontally
hoffset=0
for i in range(1,len(imgs),1):
    **hoffset=imgs[i-1].size[0]+hoffset  # update offset**
    new_im.paste(imgs[i],**(hoffset,0)**)

new_im.save('output_horizontal_montage.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution would be :

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

os.chdir('C:/Users/Sidik/Desktop/setup')
print(os.getcwd())

image_list= ['IMG_7292.jpg','IMG_7293.jpg','IMG_7294.jpg', 'IMG_7295.jpg' ]

image = [Image.open(x) for x in image_list]  # list
im_1 = image[0].rotate(270)
im_2 = image[1].rotate(270)
im_3 = image[2].rotate(270)
#im_4 = image[3].rotate(270)

height = image[0].size[0]
width = image[0].size[1]
# Create an empty white image frame
new_im = Image.new('RGB',(height*2,width*2),(255,255,255))

new_im.paste(im_1,(0,0))
new_im.paste(im_2,(height,0))
new_im.paste(im_3,(0,width))
new_im.paste(im_4,(height,width))


draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_im)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial',200)

draw.text((0, 0), '(a)', fill='white', font=font)
draw.text((height, 0), '(b)', fill='white', font=font)
draw.text((0, width), '(c)', fill='white', font=font)
#draw.text((height, width), '(d)', fill='white', font=font)

new_im.show()
new_im.save('BS1319.pdf')   
[![Laser spots on the edge][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #**How to merge cropped images back to original image**
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in images_list]
    print("Length:: ", len(images))
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    print(widths, heights)
    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = sum(heights)
    print(total_width,max_height)
    
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (5*384, 5*216))
    
    x_offset = 0
    y_offset = 0
    
    img_size = [384,216]
    def grouped(iterable, n):
        return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
    
    for x,y,a,b,c in grouped(images, 5):
        temp = []
        temp.append([x,y,a,b,c])
        print(temp[0])
        print(len(temp[0]))
        for lsingle_img in temp[0]:
            # print(lsingle_img)
            print("x_y_offset: ", (x_offset, y_offset))
            new_im.paste(lsingle_img, (x_offset, y_offset))
            x_offset += img_size[0]
        temp = []
        x_offset = 0
        y_offset += img_size[1]
    new_im.save('test.jpg')
```