# From an iteration function, how to add multiple images to a PNG file with write? (basically, is there a \n equivalent for binary files?)

Tags: python-3.x

I have an iterating function for i in [database]

Every i has with it associated multiple values, which I can extract with .operators .

I am interested in two values of each i, its name and its image.
I write each name down on a txt file with:

```
txt = open("name list.txt", "a")
txt.write(i.name)
txt.write("\n")
txt.close()
```

This gives me a basic list with all the names.
I then I try to add all images to a PNG file like so:

```
png = open("image list.png", "ab") #also tried ab+
png.write(i.image)
png.close()
```

But, even though I used append, the result is one single image, specifically the **last**. How do I add the rest?

edit: whoops, brackets.

Comment: What are you going to be opening this file in, and how exactly do you expect it to behave when it opens one file with multiple images?

Comment: You mean, what is my end goal? To have all images combined into one PNG file I can open like any other PNG.

Comment: "Any other PNG" generally only has one image. What do you expect your multi-image file to look like?

Comment: A collage of all the others basically. The first image is pasted, and then the second next to it and so forth.

Comment: You'll have to combine them into a single image before writing to the file. If you're using PIL, for example, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python).

Comment: Seems like there is no version for 3.x as of now for that? (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Comment: If you already have the images loaded in Python, just use whatever library generated them.

Comment: I see what needs to be done now, thank you. If you could repost that as an answer I can close this question.