# How can I add a white background to a video in python?

Tags: python, video

**I'm looking for a way to resize videos by adding a white background instead of changing its proportions.**

(A video with proportions 250x300px would transform to 300x300px by adding white band on each side of the video)

I've tried implementing the code I found on this thread to no result using ffmpeg, I'm very noob with image/video processing:
[Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370469/python-image-resizing-keep-proportion-add-white-background)

```
def Reformat_Image(ImageFilePath):

from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(ImageFilePath, 'r')
image_size = image.size
width = image_size[0]
height = image_size[1]

if(width != height):
    bigside = width if width > height else height

    background = Image.new('RGBA', (bigside, bigside), (255, 255, 255, 255))
    offset = (int(round(((bigside - width) / 2), 0)), int(round(((bigside - height) / 2),0)))

    background.paste(image, offset)
    background.save('out.png')
    print("Image has been resized !")

else:
    print("Image is already a square, it has not been resized !")
```

Essentially I would love to be able to do what is done in that thread, but with videos.

Any help is extremely appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg-python](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/) with **pad** video filter:

```
import ffmpeg

input = ffmpeg.input('in.avi')
output = ffmpeg.output(input, 'out.mp4', vcodec='libx264', vf='pad=w=iw+50:h=ih:x=25:y=0:color=white')

output.run()
```

---

Testing:

Create `in.avi` for testing using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=rate=10:size=250x300 -t 5 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 in.avi
```

Python execution result (last frame of `out.mp4`):

[image]

Remarks:

- The example builds `in.avi` as raw video format (without compression).
- The example encodes `out.mp4` with x264 codec (x264 / H.264 with default encoding parameters of FFmpeg).