# python merging pictures together using pyplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to tile the image to form 4 quadrants so that my image looks something like this:

[image]

However, my images come out to be something like this:

[image]

Here is what I did in terms of coding:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0,0].imshow(image1)
ax[1,0].imshow(image2)
ax[0,1].imshow(image3)
ax[1,1].imshow(image4)
plt.show()
#assuming image1~4 are different images
```

How can I merge them into a single 20x20 pixel image if each images are 10x10 pixel image?

Comment: You're using a plotting library, I would recommend you take a look at the PIL library, this answer might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30228308/4121573

Comment: Create a single array from your four images then plot that??

Comment: There are essentially two options. Both already have been asked about and got an answer.