# How to plot a matrix of images?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a bunch of images named 'arbitrary_name + index(i,j)', I would like to read those files first and combine them into a matrix-like plot which has a dimension of len(i)*len(j), each image is located in accordance with their name index. Is there any way I can do that?

In other words, use images instead of values in the heat map.

Comment: You can achieve it with subplots (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and zero margins between subplots

Comment: or concatenate images with PIL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `subplots` for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(i), ncols=len(i), sharex=True, sharey=True,)
ax = ax.flatten()
for idx in range(len(i)):    
  for jdx in range(len(j)): 
    ax[idx,jdx].imshow(the arbitrary_name_index using idx,jdx as indeces)
```

You most adjust the code to works