# Python Pillow upsize using bar lines

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am looking if there is a possible way to inside of python's pillow (I would be open to using others if it is needed) to upscale/resize a photo that is smaller than what is needed (or wrong aspect ratio). Without having the loss on the actual resolution on the original photo.

Ex if the original photo was 720 high but I needed it a total of 1080 high it would add two different white bars on the top and bottom at 180 pixels high each.

If it is possible it would help if the bar lines were white, as it would blend into a site I am uploading them onto.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Create a white image with the size you want, then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python for how to combine images.

Comment: What about the width?