# Pytorch——TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Tags: python

I'm doing an image processing task and I want to use torch.cat to concat pictures belonging to two different folders. The size of the images in folder 1 is 224*224*3, and the size of the images in folder 2 is 224*224*1.After that, I want to save the generated image.I used the save function, but I got an error, the error code is "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type".Please help me find the solution.
Here is my code:

```
import glob
import os
import torch
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.misc

f1_folder = 'F:\\picture1'
f2_folder = 'F:\\picture2'

f1_images = glob.glob(os.path.join(f1_folder, '*.jpg'))
f2_images = glob.glob(os.path.join(f2_folder, '*.jpg'))

for f1_img, f2_img in zip(f1_images, f2_images):

img1 = Image.open(f1_img)
img2 = Image.open(f2_img)

cat_img = torch.cat((TF.to_tensor(img1), TF.to_tensor(img2)), dim=1)# for 'CHW'
cat_img = cat_img.numpy()  
cat_img = np.transpose(cat_img, (1, 2, 0))  

im = Image.fromarray(cat_img)
im.save("file.jpeg")
```

Comment: Can you post the full trace back.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\conda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2428, in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
KeyError: ((1, 1, 224), '<f4')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/dataset.py", line 42, in <module>
    im = Image.fromarray(cat_img)
  File "C:\conda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2431, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Comment: what do you get on `cat_img.shape?`

Comment: Are you going to save a 4-channel array as an image? Then how is it reasonable?

Comment: Now I am using test datasets, so the size of the images in both folder 1 and 2  are 224*224*3.And  I got (448, 224, 3) on cat_img.shape.

Comment: OK, what is `cat_img.dtype`, I have seen examples using `cat_img = cat_img.astype(np.uint8)` before using `fromarray`

Comment: also, if combining the different depth an `Image.convert` might be necessary.

Comment: dtype is float32.

Comment: That might be the problem. Try if it works when converting tu `uint8`. In general 32 bit is allowed but not with RGB, I think

Comment: I hope all the fzz is not only about joining images, as this can be done much [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python)