# Is there any way to merge multiple image into one single image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, handwriting-recognition

I want to merge multiple images into one single image horizontaly.
I tried to merge images through given code but it gives white image?
For merge Images I tried PIL .

[Input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFyN4.jpg)

[Input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/541ZY.jpg)

[Input3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2oKc.jpg)

[output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMuT4.jpg)

```
import sys
from PIL import Image


def append_images(images,bg_color=(255,255,255), aligment='center'):

    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))


    new_width = sum(widths)
    new_height = max(heights)


    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (new_width, new_height), color=bg_color)

    offset = 0
    for im in images:
        y = 0
        if aligment == 'center':
            y = int((new_height - im.size[1])/2)
        elif aligment == 'bottom':
            y = new_height - im.size[1]
        new_im.paste(im, (offset, y))
        offset += im.size[0]


    return new_im
date=input("Enter Date:")
l=['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg']


images = map(Image.open,l)
combo_2 = append_images(images, aligment='center')
combo_2.save('combo_2.jpg')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine several images horizontally with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python)

Comment: The dupe target has also vertically. If this is not what you meant please say so (and explain how you want to merge the images).

Comment: I think you're offsetting the images outside of the new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer working with OpenCV&Numpy combo. That means working with arrays.
The code below simply take first image as starting point - Height. Any image you will append with it will be horizontaly stacked  based on height. That means, appended image will be resized by the montage Height and then horizontally stacked to montage.

**Working Code**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread("img1.jpg")[:,:,:3]
image2 = cv2.imread("img2.jpg")[:,:,:3]

class Montage(object):
    def __init__(self,initial_image):
        self.montage = initial_image
        self.x,self.y = self.montage.shape[:2]

    def append(self,image):
        image = image[:,:,:3]
        x,y = image.shape[0:2]
        new_image = cv2.resize(image,(int(y*float(self.x)/x),self.x))
        self.montage = np.hstack((self.montage,new_image))
    def show(self):
        cv2.imshow('montage',self.montage)
        cv2.waitKey()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Firstly, you initialize class with first image which will define HEIGHT. So if you want different height, pass into the class resized image. After that you can append horizontaly the image

**Usage**

```
>>> m = Montage(image1)
>>> m.append(image2)
>>> m.show()
```

**Result in your case:**
[image]

---

But generally it can work with totaly different sizes

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**Montage**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line:

```
images = map(Image.open,l)
```

with:

```
images = [ Image.open(im) for im in l]
```

and it all works fine.