# How to paste lot of logos sequencially on an image?

Tags: python, image

I would like to paste a lot of icons sequencially next to each other with a little bit of space on a picture

Comment: Surely when you asked your question it said you need to show what research you have done and what code you have tried?

Comment: sorry, but i actually have no idea on how to start and what to look for since i know how paste the picture but not next to each other with space

Comment: A starting point : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python

Comment: also i don`t know how to paste a picture on a certain box where can i learn about this?