# How to merge several images in a directory into a single image given the no of images in a row using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, default.png

I have a directory of images. I want to concatenate the images into a single image. If I know how many images should be merged in a row how can I achieve this in Pyhton

Comment: Are you looking for a single page per image, all of the images to to be thumbnails on one page or a combination of the two?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Add images. create a montage? adding several images into one image would most likely give you a blank or noisy image.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python