# How can I append an image to the bottom of another image using python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have two image files, of equal width, which I would like to append, so that a 750 x 750 pixel file1 and 750 x 200 pixel file2 become a 750 x 950 pixel finalFile.  How can I do this using python, preferably with PIL or pillow?

The actual task involves repeating this process to combine 20,000+ files, so manual is not an option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine several images horizontally with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python)

Comment: It should work in the same way vertically.