# Python array of url images

Tags: python, image, list, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Python jupyter notebook. Let's say that following code is using another file for extracting data from URL.

```
urls = []

for fup in data: 
    s_f = fup
    img_temp1 = s_f[7:]
    img_temp2 = s_f[6:7]
    url = ("https://google.com/%s/%s/%s/s_%s.jpg" %(img_temp1, img_temp2, s_f, s_f))
    urls.append(url)
urls
```

Data are stored in variable urls for example like this:

```
['https://google.com/3/7.jpg',
 'https://google.com/6/8.jpg',
 'https://google.com/1/5.jpg',
 'https://google.com/5/2.jpg',
 'https://google.com/9/2.jpg',
 'https://google.com/0/6.jpg',
 'https://google.com/1/2.jpg',]
```

I would love to display images horizontally. For now I'm able to display it vertically using

```
from IPython.display import Image    
display(Image(url
```

in for loop.  `

Is someone able to help me display images horizontally or for example 3 images in each row ? thanks for all help

Comment: you can use `matplotlib` and display images on plots. you can use  `PIL/pillow` to generate one image with all you images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471814/display-multiple-images-in-one-ipython-notebook-cell